# Button toggles between fa-plus and fa-minus, want "click" to only work on fa-plus. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
$(".fa-plus").parents("button").on("click",function(){
   console.log(id);
   }
});
```

The button is toggling between the + and - just fine and the accordion is opening and closing appropriately, but I'm still reading log statements from the console even when it's on fa-minus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event handler is still attached to the DOM element.

You could try something like this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/fezogeqe/20/edit?html,css,js,output).

```
var hasPlus = $target.hasClass('fa-plus');
if (hasPlus) {
  doSomething();
}
```